# How to remove comma from a csv file with quotes?

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

My Input is:

```
Name, Country, City
Jason, US, Memphis, "1,000"
David, US, Little Rock, "8,765,453"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4,678"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1,234"
```

I want output as:

```
Name, Country, City
Jason, US, Memphis, "1000"
David, US, Little Rock, "8765453"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4678"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1234"
```

I want the comma to be removed from only 4th column and not first column.

Comment: My Input is:
Name, Country, City, Amt
Jason, US, Memphis, "1,000"
David, US, Little Rock, "8,765,453"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4,678"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1,234"

I want out put as:
Name, Country, City, Amt
Jason, US, Memphis, "1000"
David, US, Little Rock, "8765453"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4678"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1234"

I want the comma to be removed from only 4th column and not first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d),(\d)/$1$2/g' infile.txt
```

which just removes all commas that are surrounded by digits (\d).

I assumed that removing thousand separators was the essence in your task - not in which column the commas are located.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 4<sup>th</sup> filed is your last filed, then an `AWK` approach would be.

```
awk -F\" '{gsub(",","",$(NF-1))}1' OFS=\" infile.txt
```

The output is:

```
Name, Country, City
Jason, US, Memphis, "1000"
David, US, Little Rock, "8765453"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4678"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1234"
```

Comment: How can we modify the command if there are n no of fields and we should delete the comma from the any field (having only numbers) which has comma.

Comment: Name, Country, City, amount, comment
Jason, US, Memphis, "1,000", "ABC,DEF"
David, US, Little Rock, "8,765,453", "DEF,GHI"
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, "4,678", "GHI, JKL"
"David, simon", US, Chicago, "1,234", "JKL, MNO"

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/,\([^"]*"$\)/\1/;ta' infile.txt
```

You loop as long as there is a comma to be removed after the next-to-last double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a CSV parser for CSV data: ruby has one

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  data = CSV.read(ARGV.shift, :col_sep => ", ")
  out = CSV.new($stdout, :col_sep => ", ")
  data.each {|row| row[-1].delete! ","; out << row}
' file.csv
```

```
Name, Country, City
Jason, US, Memphis, 1000
David, US, "Little Rock", 8765453
"Karam, Sage", US, Nazareth, 4678
"David, simon", US, Chicago, 1234
```

Comment: last field quotes `"..."`  should not be removed as OP expected output